# Disable extra joystick buttons

Tags: gamepad, joystick

I have ubuntu 13.10 and I have problem with my gamepad

I have gamepad that have buttons all messed up can I Disable some buttons?? That My joystick does not have.

So here is how it looks

[image]

This is how my other joystick looks like but some times the first joystick looks like this as well.

[image]

Any ideas how to make it work or just disable some buttons that my joystick does not have and the software thinks I am pressing??

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder the buttons and axis with `jstest-gtk` or `jscal`, however those changes are only visible to games using the old Linux joydev interface, most modern games use the evdev interface which doesn't allow any direct configuration. For games based on SDL1 you can however force the use of the old interface with:

```
export SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0
```

But this only works for a single joystick, the second one is ignored.

With SDL2 you can configure your joystick directly, it's a bit fiddly doing it manually, but you can do it via Steams BigPicture mode and it will automatically pass on the configuration.

It's also possible to create a cleaned up virtual joystick via the Linux `uinput` interface. `xboxdrv` is one tool that allows that, see the man page section `EVDEV OPTION`. Keyboard/mouse emulation is of course also possible.